# Android Linker Script - Missing PT_DYNAMIC

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, linker, linker-errors

I am attempting to run the following sample Android program that prints out the size of a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned char func_start;
extern unsigned char func_end;

int func(void) __attribute__((section(".func")));
int func(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t func_size = &func_end - &func_start;

    printf("%zu\n", func_size);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the following linker script to define the func_start and func_end variables.

```
SECTIONS
{
    .func : {
        func_start = .;
        *(.func);
        func_end = .;
    }
}
```

This code compiles with the following commands.

```
/opt/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Wall -Werror --sysroot /opt/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -o func func.c -T func.ld
```

When I attempt to run this program on a 4.4.4 Android device, I receive the following error from the linker.

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: missing PT_DYNAMIC in "./func"
```

The following shows the program headers from readelf for the output ELF.

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x14
There are 7 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x000e0 0x000e0 R   0x4
  INTERP         0x001258 0x00000258 0x00000258 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /system/bin/linker]
  LOAD           0x001000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0026b 0x0026b R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x00126b 0x0000026b 0x0000026b 0x00149 0x00149 RW  0x1000
  LOAD           0x001438 0x00000438 0x00000438 0x0001c 0x0001c R E 0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x00128c 0x0000028c 0x0000028c 0x000f0 0x000f0 RW  0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .text .plt .rel.plt .rel.dyn .note.android.ident .rodata .dynsym .dynstr .hash .interp 
   03     .data .fini_array .init_array .preinit_array .ctors .dynamic .got .bss 
   04     .func 
   05     .dynamic 
   06
```

The following shows the section headers from readelf for the output ELF.

```
There are 26 section headers, starting at offset 0x1920:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 001000 000118 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .plt              PROGBITS        00000118 001118 000038 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 3] .rel.plt          REL             00000150 001150 000018 08   A  7   0  4
  [ 4] .rel.dyn          REL             00000168 001168 000038 08   A  7   0  4
  [ 5] .note.android.ide PROGBITS        000001a0 0011a0 000018 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 6] .rodata           PROGBITS        000001b8 0011b8 000008 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 7] .dynsym           DYNSYM          000001c0 0011c0 000040 10   A  8   1  4
  [ 8] .dynstr           STRTAB          00000200 001200 000032 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 9] .hash             HASH            00000234 001234 000024 04   A  7   0  4
  [10] .interp           PROGBITS        00000258 001258 000013 00   A  0   0  1
  [11] .data             PROGBITS        0000026b 00126b 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [12] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      0000026c 00126c 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [13] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      00000274 001274 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [14] .preinit_array    PREINIT_ARRAY   0000027c 00127c 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [15] .ctors            PROGBITS        00000284 001284 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [16] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000028c 00128c 0000f0 08  WA  8   0  4
  [17] .got              PROGBITS        0000037c 00137c 000034 00  WA  0   0  4
  [18] .bss              NOBITS          000003b0 0013b0 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [19] .func             PROGBITS        00000438 001438 00001c 00  AX  0   0  4
  [20] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 001454 000035 01  MS  0   0  1
  [21] .note.gnu.gold-ve NOTE            00000000 00148c 00001c 00      0   0  4
  [22] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 0014a8 00002d 00      0   0  1
  [23] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0014d8 000240 10     24  25  4
  [24] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 001718 000116 00      0   0  1
  [25] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00182e 0000ef 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

As dynamic program header clearly exists in the ELF, I have no idea why the linker is giving me this error message.  Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

**Follow-Up**

I noticed that one of the LOAD segments actually overlaps with the DYNAMIC segment.

```
Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
LOAD           0x00126b 0x0000026b 0x0000026b 0x00149 0x00149 RW  0x1000
DYNAMIC        0x00128c 0x0000028c 0x0000028c 0x000f0 0x000f0 RW  0x4
```

Could this be causing the DYNAMIC section to be overwritten in memory which is why the linker cannot find it?

**Default Linker Script**

Assuming the problem was something with my primitive linker script, I tried to compile the program using one of the default Android toolchain linker script found in `android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/ldscripts/`.  I tried compiling with the various linker scripts here but kept receiving linker script syntax errors for the `SORT_` keywords.